# How to assign value of an object (which is inside a dictionary) to a seperate value inside a different class

Tags: python

I am creating a console based text game in Python. I have come to an issue when actually creating the player's character.

I have three classes. Character() is for the storing characters data itself, Item() is used to create an object that stores the specific item's data, and Inventory() creates a dictionary and places the defined Item()'s inside of it, then being able to be print each Item inside whenever the variable it is assigned to gets printed.

My current issue lies with the function that creates the character and gives them starting equipment.

```
def createCharacter():
    player = Character(charName, random.randint(3,6), random.randint(3,6), random.randint(10,14), random.randint(3,6))
    inventory.addItem(Item("Longsword", p.attack + 1, 0, 5))
    inventory.addItem(Item("Padded Armor", 0, p.defense + 1, 10))
```

The Longsword and Padded Armor's Attack / Defense scores are taking into consideration the player's stats when creating the Item() Object, which is what I want. However, I don't know how to then access that newly created object and replace the player's Attack / Defense with the ones stated in my inventory.

Below is my code for the three classes:

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self, name, attack, defense, health, cast):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.health = health
        self.cast = cast

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attack, defense, price):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.price = price

class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {}
    
    def addItem(self, item):
        self.items[item.name] = item
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        out = ""
        for item in self.items.values():
            out += '\t'.join([str(x) for x in [item.name, item.attack, item.defense, item.price]]) + '\n'
        return out

inventory = Inventory()
```

Comment: `inventory` shouldn't be a global variable. Each character should have their own inventory.

Comment: @Barmar How would I end up attaching the inventory to the Character?

Comment: `self.inventory = Inventory()` in the `__init__()` method. Then use `self.inventory.addItem()` to add to it.